# `nl` invocation soaking all input before numbering

Tags: command-line, logs, console, nl, tracing

How can this be done?

I don't see any applicable option in the manual.

I have positively checked that indentation breaks after ten million lines.

You can check it like:

```
$ (for i in `seq 0 10000000`; do echo "$i"; done) | nl
```

I don't often generate so many lines, but I don't want it to break like it does. How can this be done?

Comment: I doubt it is in `nl` that's the bottleneck. Counter-test: `seq -s$'\n' 0 10000000 | nl` (if your `seq` supports `-s`)

Comment: @muru, that's just `seq 0 10000000 | nl` here. `seq` outputs numbers one per line. That's `\`...\`` soaking the seq output, that's what it's meant to do.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I didn't remember seq's default separator, but the point remains that nl isn't to blame here.

Comment: Well `seq 0 10000000 | nl | head` is a faster test case. Is this question really about the default width of the field reserved for space padding (right-alignment)?

Comment: My `nl` version is not providing an option to soak up all standard input before writing its standard output. I'ld desire such an option. Do you know any workaround for such a not existing option?

Comment: You could probably pipe the output to `column -t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are suggesting that `nl` should buffer the entire input simply to measure the maximum required number, that is not in the spirit of stream filters at all. With rare exceptions (`sort`, for instance), core utilities try to process streams immediately -- especially as they may be used in a virtually infinite pipeline (for instance, a loging stream that is incrementally filtered through `nl` and redirected into a file could accumulate quite a lot of data).

The standard way to handle padding is to simply specify the maximal expected width as a parameter. In this case, you can either turn off padding (I prefer this anyway, it makes sense to just have space separated column at the front), or set a different width. Compare:

```
seq 0 10000000 | nl -w12 # default right-justify, 12 character width

seq 0 10000000 | nl -w1 # default right-justify, 1 character width (no padding)

seq 0 10000000 | nl -w1 -s' ' # right-justify, space delimited instead of tab

seq 0 10000000 | nl -nln # left-justify
```

If you *really* want to do this automatically, just use `wc -l` to first measure the length and then set the `-w` appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The `seq 0 10000000` is expanding to ten million and one lines, which `bash` needs to store in its memory so that it can loop over the values. *That* is what breaks, I managed to terminate it before it used up all the memory + swap on my system (I didn't want the out-of-memory to kill some other process, although modern kernels will correctly determine which process to kill).

You can check it's not `nl` by replacing `nl` with `cat` or `wc` or whatever other command that reads its input.

muru's version should be equivalent without requiring `bash` to store all that data intermediately.

EDIT: if it is about the number padding, I would have expected that a 10 second read of the manpage would have led to the `nl -w` option... Use `nl -w8`. If you're then unsatisfied with the large gap between line number and line contents (due to the default tab being used), you can add `-s' '`; it's all there in the manpage, easily found. I'm still wondering why the for loop in the question though.

Comment: I don't think this is what he asked. I think it's about the number padding.

Comment: @orion is right.